# Alternative to polling database in Windows Form?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, timer, .net-4.0

We have two Windows Forms: `FormSqlUpdater` and `FormReader`. `FormSqlUpdater` updates an SQL table and `FormReader` reads from that same SQL table. This means that `FormReader` needs to be polling the database continually; When `FormSqlUpdater` changes the SQL table, the change is reflected through a `TextBox` in `FormReader`. I would like to make this as *real-time* as possible.

So many of the suggestions have been to use a `Timer`. Considering that this needs to be as *real-time* as possible, I have a feeling that if I set the `Timer` to poll the database too often (i.e., every three seconds) then this lag will be noticed by the user. Also, if the query takes too long for whatever reason, this lag will also be noticed by the user. And if I set the Timer for too long, then the Forms won't be synchronized. Either way, I don't feel too comfortable with a Timer.

So I was thinking of using the `FileSystemWatcher` in `FormReader`; when `FormSqlUpdater` updates the DB, it will write to a text file. Once `FileSystemWatcher` in `FormReader` notices that the text file has been changed, then `FormReader` will update itself.

At least for me, it seems that using `FileSystemWatcher` this way is possibly a better alternative.

What are your thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: Polling continuously does seem bad to me, as well.  I would favor a signaling approach of some kind, although writing to a file seems a bit cludgy.  If it's two forms in the same app, just create a method in the reader that the updater can call to say "hey, I wrote new data, go get it".

Comment: The issue is that each form will be running on a different devices at different locations. Even if the forms are in the same project, I don't think your suggestion would work since they're in different locations.

Comment: Then what about writing it as a piece of data _in the database_?

Comment: that file will have to be on a server so any running instance of the application can find it. Accesing a file on a server might be even slower than reading a table in the database. Also you will have to worry about 2 applications trying to read/write the same file at the same time, We solved this by making a table with just one record and just one column, the datetime the last changes where made. Reading this in a timer is much faster and more reliable than the file method

Comment: @DonBoitnott, the issue is not finding a shared resource (ie. file, database, etc). It's the polling.

Comment: @GuidoG, so you're saying that setting the `Timer` so it polls the DB every 3 seconds is faster and more reliable than `FileSystemWatcher` _polling_ the file? _And_ the user won't notice that _something's_ happening every 3 seconds?

Comment: the user will notice it on both situations. Even when polling every 3 seconds the form will not get updated unless there is a change, right ? So the user will not see more or less updates in the form with either method.

Comment: If both applications have access to the same file system, then can't you connect the two of them, using WCF or any other method? Then `FormSqlUpdater` could send a message to `FormReader` as soon as it updates the DB.

Comment: @Eli, would this work even if each form is running on a different device at different locations?

Comment: Are Query Notifications an option for you?  Seems like the right approach.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: A [`SqlDependency`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953(v=vs.110).aspx) object can be associated with a SqlCommand in order to detect when query results differ from those originally retrieved. You can also assign a delegate to the OnChange event, which will fire when the results change for an associated command. You must associate the SqlDependency with the command before you execute the command. The HasChanges property of the SqlDependency can also be used to determine if the query results have changed since the data was first retrieved.

Comment: The issue is that there has to be some type of _listener_ in  the form. What use would Query Notifications be if the form isn't listening to those notifications?

Comment: @RezaAghaei, I posted a question directly related to `SqlDependency` here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38024866/sqldependency-onchange-not-firing-in-winform)